# SQL Syntax Error (INSERT command)

Tags: c#, sql

I have a form with a text box and button, such that when the user clicks the button, the specified name in the text box is added to a table in my sql database.  The code for the button is as follows:

```
private void btnAddDiaryItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       string strNewDiaryItem = txtAddDiaryItem.Text;
       if (strNewDiaryItem.Length == 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("You have not specified the name of a new Diary Item");
           return;
       }
       string sqlText = "INSERT INTO tblDiaryTypes (DiaryType) VALUES = ('" + strNewDiaryItem + "');";
       cSqlQuery cS = new cSqlQuery(sqlText, "non query");
       PopulateInitialDiaryItems();
       MessageBox.Show("New Diary Item added succesfully");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

The class cSqlQuery is a simple class that executes various T-SQL actions for me and its code is as follows:

```
class cSqlQuery
{
    public string cSqlStat;
    public DataTable cQueryResults;
    public int cScalarResult;

    public cSqlQuery()
    {
        this.cSqlStat = "empty";
    }

    public cSqlQuery(string paramSqlStat, string paramMode)
    {
        this.cSqlStat = paramSqlStat;

        string strConnection = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        if (paramMode == "non query")
        {
            linkToDB.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(paramSqlStat, linkToDB);
            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            linkToDB.Close();
        }

        if (paramMode == "table")
        {
            using (linkToDB)
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cSqlStat, linkToDB))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                this.cQueryResults = table;
            }
        }

        if (paramMode == "scalar")
        {
            linkToDB.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(paramSqlStat, linkToDB);
            this.cScalarResult = (Int32)sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
            linkToDB.Close();
        }
    }

    public cSqlQuery(SqlCommand paramSqlCom, string paramMode)
    {
        string strConnection = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        paramSqlCom.Connection = linkToDB;

        if (paramMode == "table")
        {
            using (linkToDB)
            using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(paramSqlCom))
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                this.cQueryResults = table;
            }
        }

        if (paramMode == "scalar")
        {
            linkToDB.Open();
            paramSqlCom.Connection = linkToDB;
            this.cScalarResult = (Int32)paramSqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
            linkToDB.Close();
        }
    }

    public string BuildConnectionString()
    {
        cConnectionString cCS = new cConnectionString();
        return cCS.strConnect;
    }        
}
```

The class works well throughout my application so I don't think the error is in the class, but then I can't be sure.

When I click the button I get the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near =

Which is really annoying me, because when I run the exact same command in SQL Management Studio it works fine.

I'm sure I'm missing something rather simple, but after reading my code through many times, I'm struggling to see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Look into parameterized queries. Never go to the database with unsanitized user input.

Comment: try entering this in the form: `MyDiaryItem'); DROP TABLE tblDiaryTypes`. Then read some of the links in this google search: http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need the =

A valid insert would look like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: damn it - I said it would be something simple :s  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 11):

you have to remove = after values.

```
string sqlText = "INSERT INTO tblDiaryTypes (DiaryType) VALUES ('" + strNewDiaryItem + "');"
```

and try to use Parameterized  queries to avoid Sql injection. use your code like this. [Sql Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)

```
 string sqlText = "INSERT INTO tblDiaryTypes (DiaryType) VALUES (@DairyItem);"
    YourCOmmandObj.Parameters.AddwithValue("@DairyItem",strNewDiaryIItem)
```

Answer (score 10):

Remove the `=` after `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following:

```
insert into <table name> Values (value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove "=", and also i would recommend you to use string.format() instead of string concatenation.

`sqlText = string.format(INSERT INTO tblDiaryTypes (DiaryType) VALUES ('{0}'), strNewDiaryItem);"`

Comment: String.Format is not going to save you here. Never directly use user input in a SQL query. Use parameterized queries instead.